# 2sls for panel data in R

Tags: panel-data, 2sls

My question is how to do 2sls estimation for panel data (fixed effects) in **R software**?
I try to use ivreg but I cannot set fixed effects option there.
Any suggestion would be good!

Answer (score 4):

Use the plm package, see [this vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/plm.pdf) - page 17. The call should be:

```
require(plm)
data("Crime", package = "plm")
2slsfd_reg <- plm(log(crmrte) ~ log(prbarr) + factor(year) | . - log(prbarr) 
              log(taxpc) + log(mix), data = Crime,
              model = "fd")
summary(2slsfd_reg)
```

This works, more or less, the same as way the usual ivreg, i.e. you specify the instruments after the pipe operator.

You should be warned, for large dataset plm can be very slow. It is good practice to create a separate p.data.frame (p for panel) before the call to plm. For small datasets, you could do it on the fly... Have fun

Comment: Thank you Repmat for the answer! It works well with FE, though I can't add "twoway" effect. I get error: Error in crossprod(t(X), beta) : non-conformable arguments. Moreover, I would like to ask about causal effects. According to the pages 17-18 (same source as above), log(prbarr) and log(polpc) are endogenous variables, so they are instrumented with log(taxpc) and log(mix), right? I am not sure how I must check for causality of prbarr and polpc on the dependent variable. Does it mean that if they are both significant then they both have causal effect on the dependent variable?

Comment: That seems strange, but can't just include the times dummuies, as a factor, yourself?

Comment: I suppose I could, but it's not the biggest issue at the moment - it was just a try. However, I would be grateful if you could answer my question about causality. Any suggestion?

Comment: I not sure I understand you. You suspect (or the vignette does), that prbarr and polpc are endogenoues to the equation. As such, you can't trust the estimates obtained from using them. Therefore you use the IV to try and correct this problem. Once you have the 2SLS estimates, in the linear model, the interepration is the same as always...

Comment: Alright, I got it. Do you know if there is any way to report the first stage of 2sls using the syntax mentioned above? The instrumental variable estimation is "Balestra-Varadharajan-Krishnakumar's transformation".

Comment: I don't know. Maybe have a look at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/plm.pdf ? - but the real question is, why do want these?

Comment: I would like to see how valid is the instrument I am trying to use in my 2sls.